# Xpages checkbox group multiple columns?

Tags: css, checkbox, xpages, multiple-columns

I want to format a checkbox group into 2 or more columns.

I have read about a CSS3 solution using display, width, and float. It doesn't appear to work in IE9+.

Is there a simple solution to doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A long while ago I wrote a multi-column component. Hasn't been tested on 9.x, but might work. Have a look at the [OpenNTF Project](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Multi%20Column%20Controls). That might just do the trick.

Comment: It works in 9.01, but this seems like an awful lot of trouble to do something as common as trying to layout a field into two columns, even though you've done most of the work with the custom control. I had seen your openntf project before, but I though in 5+ years, someone might have found an easier way.

Comment: There might be a CSS3 way - which will probably break in some browsers