# I am using Check box group with computed values(Vertical layout). The display of my page is not user freindly as all the 20 values are verticall align

Tags: xpages-ssjs

I am using checkbox group with vertical layout. Computed values are used for its values that return all the department managers names. and we have a long list of department managers. The checkbox is returning the correct values but the display is out and users have to scroll it down. is there any possibility through which I can display them in different columns or any way around to avoid the scrolling.

Comment: Use a value picker control instead?

Comment: Have a look at this question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894907/xpages-checkbox-group-multiple-columns